# How to redirect the user to a new html page through jsp?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a html page called Login.html which is a simple login page with username and password and a submit button. On click of the submit button a JSP page called Login.jsp is called which checks for the validity of username and password using SQL database.
The thing i wanted to do is If the USERNAME and PASSWORD are correct i wanted the REDIRECT the user to a new html page called Site.html . But i cant find how to redirect to that page.
The code of Login.jsp is

```
  try{
Connection con=null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:base","root","root");

String username= request.getParameter("uname");
String password= request.getParameter("pass");
String query = "SELECT * FROM users where uname=? AND pass=?";
stmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1,username);
stmt.setString(2,password);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    if(rs.next())
   {
    out.println("Success");<%-- This is where i want to write the redirecting code --%>
   }
   else
   {
  out.println("Fail");
   }
 }
catch(Exception e)
{
 out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` and `response` object's are implicitly available in jsp as well, just like in servlet. So you can do

```
  if(rs.next())
   {
    response.sendRedirect(pathOfredirectingJSP);
   }
```

Comment: That did it! Didnt know response and request are implicitly available! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
     if(rs.next())
     {
        out.println("Success");
        String redirectURL = "http://whatever.com/myJSPFile.jsp";
        response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
     }
```